# Ramda JS how to map a specific value using 2 json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ramda.js

the issue im having is im using 2 json file to map out the status of the event and im not sure how to do it in ramda

```
const input1 = {
              data: {
                memberId: 12345,
                orderStatus: pack
              },
              Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z',
              statusType: 'order',
            }

const input2 = {
              data: {
                memberId: 12345,
                deliveryStatus: dispatch
              },
              Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z',
              statusType: 'delivery',
            }

const input3 = {
              data: {
                memberId: 12345,
              },
              Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z',
              statusType: 'new',
            }

const status = {
  'order': {
      orderStatus: {
        pack: 'order is being pack',
        cancelled: 'cancel order'
    },
  },
  'delivery': {
      deliveryStatus: {
        pending: 'pending',
        dispatch: 'order has been delivered'
    },
  },
  'new': 'newly made'
}
```

1. Console log input1 : "order is being pack"
2. Console log input2 : "order has been delivered"
3. Console log input3 : "newly made"

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### An ugly solution

We can do that without Ramda, in a somewhat complex manner:

```js
const statusHandler = (statuses) => {
  const handlers = Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (status)
    .map (([name, val]) => typeof val == 'string'
      ? [name, () => val]
      : [name, ({data}) => val [name + 'Status'] [data [name + 'Status']]]
    ))
 
  return (item) => handlers [item .statusType] (item)
}
 
const status = {
  order: {
    orderStatus: {
      pack: 'order is being pack', 
      cancelled: 'cancel order'
    }
  }, 
  delivery: {
    deliveryStatus: {
      pending: 'pending', 
      dispatch: 'order has been delivered'
    }
  }, 
  new: 'newly made'
}
 
const getStatus = statusHandler (status)
 
const input1 = {data: {memberId: 12345, orderStatus: 'pack'}, Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z', statusType: 'order'}
const input2 = {data: {memberId: 12345, deliveryStatus: 'dispatch'}, Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z', statusType: 'delivery'}
const input3 = {data: {memberId: 12345}, Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z', statusType: 'new'}
 
console .log (getStatus (input1))
console .log (getStatus (input2))
console .log (getStatus (input3))
```

I don't see that Ramda would offer much simplification here, perhaps shortening things slightly with `fromPairs` and `toPairs` in place of `Object .fromEntries` and `Object .entries`, or even better with Ramda's `map`, which works on objects, and perhaps some additional simplification by using `pipe`, but it would not clean up the main problem with this, that the keys we search for have to be constructed and that our configuration object, `status` contains two different structures rather than being consistent for all.

I have no idea if that `status` object is imposed on you and you simply have to deal with it or if it's of your own construction.  Below I will discuss ways to clean it up, but first, there's one thing we might want to do to handle at least one possible failure case:

### Handling missing `statusType`s

If the `statusType` is not in our list of types, then this will fail.  Perhaps your data is consistent enough that this could never happen, but I've far too often seen supposedly impossible data situations bring down an application.  So this extension might make it cleaner.

```
const statusHandler = (statuses) => {
  const handlers = Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (status)
    .map (([name, val]) => typeof val == 'string'
      ? [name, () => val]
      : [name, ({data}) => val [name + 'Status'] [data [name + 'Status']]]
    ))
  const defaultHandler = () => 'unknown status type'  // New line

  return (item) => (handlers [item .statusType] || defaultHandler) (item)  // Updated
}
```

That will let us handle cases like this:

```
const input4 = {data: {memberId: 12345}, Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z', statusType: 'foobar'}

getStatus (input4) //=> unknown status type
```

### Cleaning up the configuration object

The complexity here lies within the configuration object.  We handle the `new` case with a different structure from `order` and `delivery`.  And we nest the messages at what looks like an unnecessary extra level (why not move the contents of `orderStatus` and `deliveryStatus` up to their parents?)  As I said, this may be an existing structure that we have no control over, and the answer above may be the best that we can do.  But if we have control over this structure, then this is more explicit, and leads to cleaner code:

```js
const statusHandler = (statuses) => (item) => {
  const type = statuses [item .statusType] || statuses ['*']
  return type [item .data [item .statusType + 'Status'] || '*']
}

const status = {
  order: {
    pack: 'order is being pack', 
    cancelled: 'cancel order',
    '*': 'unknown order status'
  }, 
  delivery: {
    pending: 'pending', 
    dispatch: 'order has been delivered',
    '*': 'unknown delivery status'
  }, 
  new: {
    '*': 'newly made'   
  },
  '*': {
    '*': 'unknown status type'
  }
}
```

This also accounts for another potential failure:

```
const input5 = {data: {memberId: 12345, status: 'collection'}, Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z', statusType: 'order'}

getStatus (input5) //=> unknown order status
```

We probably have actually made our line-count longer here, because of the additions to the configuration object.  But overall, it's much *simpler*.  Our configuration object completely describes the kind of output we get for any combination of status and stage.  Our code simply translates that into a function from our data item.

You can see it in action in this snippet:

```js
const statusHandler = (statuses) => (item) => {
  const type = statuses [item .statusType] || statuses ['*']
  return type [item .data [item .statusType + 'Status'] || '*']
}

const status = {
  order: {
    pack: 'order is being pack', 
    cancelled: 'cancel order',
    '*': 'unknown order status'
  }, 
  delivery: {
    pending: 'pending', 
    dispatch: 'order has been delivered',
    '*': 'unknown delivery status'
  }, 
  new: {
    '*': 'newly made'   
  },
  '*': {
    '*': 'unknown status type'
  }
}
 
const getStatus = statusHandler (status)
 
const input1 = {data: {memberId: 12345, orderStatus: 'pack'}, Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z', statusType: 'order'}
const input2 = {data: {memberId: 12345, deliveryStatus: 'dispatch'}, Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z', statusType: 'delivery'}
const input3 = {data: {memberId: 12345}, Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z', statusType: 'new'}
const input4 = {data: {memberId: 12345}, Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z', statusType: 'foobar'}
const input5 = {data: {memberId: 12345, status: 'collection'}, Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z', statusType: 'order'}
 
console .log (getStatus (input1))
console .log (getStatus (input2))
console .log (getStatus (input3))
console .log (getStatus (input4))
console .log (getStatus (input5))
```

### Cleaning up duplication in our items

Finally, even if we have control over this configuration object, we might not have control over the input data objects.  But if we do, there is some redundancy in there that not only is unnecessary but also causes us to do an annoying string manipulation in our function:

```
const input1 = {
              data: {
                memberId: 12345,
                orderStatus: pack
              },
              Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z',
              statusType: 'order',
            }
```

We declare the `statusType` of **`order`**, but then set the **`orderStatus`** to `pack`.  There is a clear argument for replacing `orderStatus` with just plain `status`.  So if we have control over that data as well, we would have more consistent data, and our function could be simpler still.

We can see that possibility in this snippet:

```js
const statusHandler = (statuses) => (item) => {
  const type = statuses [item .statusType] || statuses ['*']
  return type [item .data .status || '*'] || type ['*']
}

const status = {
  order: {
    pack: 'order is being pack', 
    cancelled: 'cancel order',
    '*': 'unknown order status'
  }, 
  delivery: {
    pending: 'pending', 
    dispatch: 'order has been delivered',
    '*': 'unknown delivery status'
  }, 
  new: {
    '*': 'newly made'   
  },
  '*': {
    '*': 'unknown status type'
  }
}
 
const getStatus = statusHandler (status)
 
const input1 = {data: {memberId: 12345, status: 'pack'}, Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z', statusType: 'order'}
const input2 = {data: {memberId: 12345, status: 'dispatch'}, Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z', statusType: 'delivery'}
const input3 = {data: {memberId: 12345}, Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z', statusType: 'new'}
const input4 = {data: {memberId: 12345}, Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z', statusType: 'foobar'}
const input5 = {data: {memberId: 12345, status: 'collection'}, Time: '2019-08-12T08:55:28Z', statusType: 'order'}
 
console .log (getStatus (input1))
console .log (getStatus (input2))
console .log (getStatus (input3))
console .log (getStatus (input4))
console .log (getStatus (input5))
```

### Lessons

We can simplify our code by making our data structures simpler and more consistent.  That allows us to make our whole system more declarative.  Note that the final function is not only simpler, it's also much more likely to be reusable across different parts of our application or different applications.

Comment: thank you that was a nice example and explanation this will help newbe like me to understand more about ramda